# Verify google recaptcha

Tags: axios, recaptcha

I want to verify the recaptcha that I get form a input form. By having the secret and response I tried everything that I found on the internet in 3 hours. But couldn't solve the problem.
Here is my code:

```
const app = express()
app.get('/check', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await axios.post(
    `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret}&response=${response}`,
    {},
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
      },
    },
  );
  return res.send(result.data);
})
```

`����RPP*.MNN-.V�RHK�)N�����&秤�ģ�B@�̼�Ĝ��̼��ݢ�����T%�d,W-�� K`

and this is output:

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Try and update to v1.21, I was seeing the same issue. Possibly related to https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5336.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the problem. So I change to 'axios' to 'superagent', and it works well.

Comment: It had a defect in v1.2.0, new version v1.2.1 fixed it.